# Mongo DB updateOne query calculation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have this Schema:

```
const HeroSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
power_start: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
},
power_current: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0
}
})
```

When a user clicks a button I want to randomly add 'power' between 1-10 to 'power_current'. Means, I need the final number in 'power_current' to be the sum of 'power_start' + random number + 'power_current'

'power start' getting random number as the default.

I just started to write and stuck:

```
updateHeroPower: async({id})=>{
   const res = await HeroSchema.updateOne({
       _id: id
   },{
       $set:{
        
       }
   }) 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use [Updates with Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

Comment: An example will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For Mongo version 4.2+ you can use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) like so:

```
const res = await HeroSchema.updateOne({
        _id: id
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                power_current: {$sum: ["$power_current", "$power_start", Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Older Mongo version do not have the power to access document fields within the update object.
This means you'll have to split it into 2 calls. First read the document and only then update it using the information you fetched.

One thing to note is I'm not sure you actually want the logic you requested as summing `power_current` and `power_start` every single time will actually inflate the score. I think what you want to do is sum `random` with `power_start` if `power_current` does not exist, and otherwise sum it with `power_current` as it already embodies `power_start` value after the initial sum.

Assuming my assumption is correct you can achieve this with [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)

```
const res = await HeroSchema.updateOne({
        _id: id
    },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                power_current: {$sum: [{$ifNull: ["$power_current", "$power_start"]}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```